# Audio Player for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, avaudioplayer

I want to develop an audio player for window phone8. I've created UI for this. Now I want to play the songs already saved in isolated storage of phone. I don't have any idea what to do. Can anyone help me for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could reproduce this sample according to yours:

```
MediaElement media = new MediaElement();

using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
  using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
     media.SetSource(fileStream);
     media.Play();
  }
}
```

You could have a look at these too:

- [How do you Automatically open(play) file after it is saved to isolation storage? WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466936/)
- [Playing media file from Isolated Storage in windows phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357083/)